# Querying related documents

Tags: node.js, mongoose, querying

I am working on an admin system for managing courses and their tutorials.

Let's say I have the following schemas:

```
var TutorialSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    number: { type: String, required: true }
});

var CourseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    code: { type: String,  required: true, unique: true },
    tutorials: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Tutorial' }]
});
```

Each course has a name e.g. Intro to Web Programming and a **unique** code e.g. CSCC09. Each tutorial has a **non-unique** number e.g. 0001. Two courses will have tutorials with the same number. However, each tutorial within a course will have a different number.

Currently, when the user goes to edit a tutorial, it goes through the following route:

```
router.get('/courses/:code/tutorials/:number/edit', function (req, res) { 
    Course.findOne({ 
        code: req.params.code 
    }).populate({ 
        path: 'tutorials', match: { number: req.params.number }
    }).exec(function (err, course) {
        res.render('admin/tutorial', { course: course, tutorial: course.tutorials[0], method: 'put' });
    });
});
```

The reason why I do it this way is to ensure that the tutorial matched is for the appropriate course.

So, for my question, is there a cleaner way to query related models?

I would prefer to do something like below, but I cannot because the tutorial that is matched may not be for the related course:

```
Course.findOne({ code: req.params.code}, function (err, course) {
    Tutorial.findOne({ number: req.params.number }, function (err, tutorial) {
        // ...
    });
});
```

I am aware that I can use the IDs of the documents, however I am looking to have readable URLs (so that it will allow users to quickly go to pages from the browser's URL bar).

Answer (score -1):

You should use the mongoose-relationship librarie. It make it more easy.

```
    var mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    relationship = require("mongoose-relationship");

    var ParentSchema = new Schema({
       children:[{ type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:"Child" }]
    });
    var Parent = mongoose.model("Parent", ParentSchema);

    var ChildSchema = new Schema({
        parent: { type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:"Parent", childPath:"children" }
    });
    ChildSchema.plugin(relationship, { relationshipPathName:'parent'});
    var Child = mongoose.model("Child", ChildSchema)

     var parent = new Parent({});
     parent.save();
     var child = new Child({parent:parent._id});
     child.save() //the parent children property will now contain child's id
     child.remove() //the parent children property will no longer contain the child's id
```